# Proof Verification: If $g\circ f$ is surjective, Prove that $g$ is surjective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory

It's given that $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to C$.

My Proof:

If $g\circ f$ is surjective then all elements $z∈C$ can be written as $g(f(x))$ where $x∈A$.

We know that for all $x∈A$, $f(x)∈B$ and that for all elements $y∈B$, $g(y)∈C$. Let S be the set containing all elements of $B$ which can be written as $f(x)$, where $x∈A$. Now the set of all $g(s)$,where $s∈S$ would be equal to the set C since the set of all $g(s)$ is the set of all $g(f(x))$. This implies that g is surjective.

Please verify if this is logically correct and rigorous enough.

Comment: "Let S be the set containing all elements of B which can be written as f(x), where x∈C. "  That could very well be empty If $A \cap C = \emptyset$.

Comment: If the sentence "If $g\circ f$ is surjective then... where $x\in A$" is transformed into "If $g\circ f$ is surjective then... where $f(x)\in B$, hence $g$ is surjective" then the proof is complete and rigorous. The rest is of no use and only confusing.

Comment: No.  This is nearly impossible to read.  It's unclear why any statment follows for any other and when I do hack through it, its completely wrong.... what you need to prove is that if $c \in C$ that there must exists a $b \in B$ so that $g(b) = c$.  And you are allowed to assume  that if $c \in C$ then there must exist an $a \in A$ so that $g(f(a)) = c$.

Comment: "Now the set of all g(s),where s∈S would be equal to the set C .... This implies that g is surjective."  It was really hard to read that sentence.  And then I had to ask why?  Perhaps it'd be clearer if you put in a statment that $S \subset B$.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't write it like that. Usually surjectivity of a function $f: X \to Y$ is proven in the following way:

Take $y \in Y$, and find an element $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$

---

Let's do this now:

Take $c \in C$. Since $g \circ f$ is surjective, there exists $a \in A$ such that $g(f(a)) = (g \circ f)(a) = c$ and $f(a)$ is the element we are looking for.

Comment: Still, is my proof incorrect? If it is, please point out where it is logically incorrect and/or not rigorous enough.

Comment: You are not very precise. Write out the sets in symbols. Moreover, your proof is very hard to read so I actually didn't bother.

Comment: @ArjunNigam: First, ask yourself what is the definition of surjectivity (as this answer does). Then you need to show that $g$ satisfies that definition.

Comment: Yeah I guess mine is wordy and hard to read compared to yours. Thanks for the answer. I think my answer was unnecessarily long but reading both of our proofs, I think the main idea is the same.

Comment: The idea is certainly there, but the presentation could be better. Don't worry about it, that's common for people learning basic formal math!

Comment: After some thinking I came up with a concise proof that presents the same idea as my original proof. Please verify if this is correct. The proof: $∀ c∈C∃ a∈A:c=g(f(a))$. $∀ a∈A∃ b∈B:f(a)=b$. If $f(a)=b$ then g(f(a))=g(b). So we can say that $∀ a∈A∃ b∈B:g(f(a))=g(b)$. From this we can conclude that $∀ c∈C∃ b∈B:c=g(b)$

Comment: Yes, conceptually it is correct and you would get all points (at least if I were your instructor), but nobody writes it like that. All these quantors make the thing very unreadable. If you want to prove something like $\forall x: P(x)$, you fix an $x$ and you show that $P(x)$ is true. Then, the statement follows because $x$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

> If $g \circ f$ is surjective then all elements $z \in C$ can be written $g(f(x))$ where $x \in A$.

True enough.  It might be slightly clearer to say "... can be written $z=g(f(x))$ where $x \in $A".

One slight problem with this beginning is that the way the sentence is, the starting point of "$g \circ f$ is surjective" modifies just the one sentence.  But you want that to be the assumption for the entire proof.  So I would write this instead something like:

"Suppose $g \circ f$ is surjective.  This means any element $z \in C$ can be written $z=g(f(x))$ where $x \in A$."

> We know that for all $x \in A$, $f(x)\in B$ and that for all elements $y \in B$, $g(y) \in C.$

This sentence is just repeating the given that $f : A \to B$ and $g : B \to C$.  I don't think it adds anything to the proof, especially since you don't obviously and directly use the statements in that form.

> Let $S$ be the set containing all elements of $B$ which can be written as $f(x)$, where $x \in A$.

Have you come across the term "image" of a function?  This would be an excellent place to use it, so that any other reader familiar with the term can immediately associate what they know about it:

"Let $S$ be the image of $f$; that is, the set containing all elements of $B$ which can be written as $f(x)$, where $x \in A$."

(Or if I could assume everyone in the intended audience of my proof understands "image", I might just write "Let $S \subseteq B$ be the image of $f$.")

> Now the set of all $g(s)$, where $s \in S$ would be equal to the set $C$ since the set of all $g(s)$ is the set of all $g(f(x))$.

Here I'm not too comfortable following this.  Doing arguments on transformations on "the set of all..." is not the usual rigorous approach, and I wouldn't be surprised if in some situations it could lead you to a false conclusion.

The usual and safer way is to demonstrate things about sets by demonstrating things about elements of those sets.  This involves phrases like "for all" (or "for each" or "for every"), abbreviated $\forall$, and "there exists", abbreviated $\exists$.

So one way to write the definition of surjective is:

A function $\varphi : X \to Y$ is called **surjective** if $\forall y \in Y\: \exists x \in X : y=\varphi(x)$.

Backing up, I would write this proof like the following:

Given $f : A \to B$ and $g : B \to C$, prove that if $g \circ f$ is surjective, then $g$ is surjective.

**Proof**:

Suppose $g \circ f$ is surjective.  That is, $\forall z \in C\: \exists x \in A : z = (g \circ f)(x)$.

Let $z$ be any element of $C$.  We know there is some $x \in A$ with $z = (g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$.

So let $y = f(x)$.  Then $z = g(y)$.

This shows $\forall z \in C\: \exists y \in B : z = g(y)$, so $g$ is surjective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I said that the set of all g(s) is equal to C, I said that because all elements of C can be written as g(f(x)) and we defined S as the set containing all elements of B that were in the form of f(x). Thus the set of all g(s) would be to the set of all g(f(x)) which is equal to C. Is it still not clear or not rigorous? I still don't quite understand the exact reason that my proof isn't correct. I will acknowledge that it is unnecessarily wordy though.

Answer (score 0):

Another proof: Suppose that $g$ is *non*-surjective, namely there exists some $c\in C$ such that for all $b\in B$, $g(b)\neq c$. Thus, we have 
$$g\circ f=g(f(a))\neq c,$$
since $f(a)\in B$. Can you conclude from here? (Spoiler below)

> The above equation shows that $g\circ f$ is non-surjective. By [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition), we get the desired result.